# Concatenate string names

Tags: java, string

Its a very strange question but I was thinking if there is any solution for it?

Scenerio is that I want to concatenate a String name

Like there is a String:

```
public static final String MYSQL_USERNAME = "mysql_user";
public static final String DB2_USERNAME = "db2admin";
public static final String ORACLE_USERNAME = "oracleuser";
```

...

```
if(dbType == "mysql"){
   username = "MYSQL"+_username;
   ...
}else if(dbType == "db2"){
   username = "DB2"+_username;
   ...
}else if(dbType == "oracle"){
   username = "ORACLE"+_username;
   ...
}
```

i.e. at runtime I want to concatenate String based on dbType and fetch username.

Basically I want to make `"MYSQL"+_username = MYSQL_USERNAME`

I want to avoid these 3 if's

There should be only 1 line

```
username = dbType+_username;
```

Comment: I am not getting your question. String literals are *compile time constants*.

Comment: Please don't use `==` to compare strings. Use `.equals` instead.

Comment: What you're asking for is possible using reflection, but it's more than 1 line and is not an approach I'd recommend for this particular problem.

Comment: Based on your very last line, doesn't `username = dbType.toUpperCase() + _username` resolve the issue?

Comment: I think OP want to define String variable name at runtime

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bad solution.

A better one would use database-specific .properties files with identical key names for each database.  Your code need not know or care which database you're connecting to that way.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a map with the user names.

```
public static final Map<String, String> userNames = new HashMap<>();
{
    userNames.put("mysql",  "mysql_user");
    userNames.put("db2",    "db2admin");
    userNames.put("oracle", "oracleuser");
}
```

Then you can look up the desired entry in the map given the database name.

```
userName = userNames.get(dbType);
```